# method to circumvent if-else checking

Tags: if-statement, numpy, optimization, conditional-statements, vectorization

I am just wondering if I want to implement a program that converts wavelength to (r,g,b) using the algorithm in this paper (p5-6): http://www.scientificbulletin.upb.ro/rev_docs_arhiva/full49129.pdf, instead of checking the value of wavelength using if-else like

```
if wavelength>380 and wavelength<410:
    # do something
elif wavelength<440:
    # do something
elif wavelength<490:
    # do something, and so on
```

Are there some genius method to avoid using if-else statement so that I can speed up the code? More specifically, suppose I store the wavelengths in a list or a numpy array, is it possible to have some sort of 'vectorized' method to generate the (r,g,b) values?

Comment: What is `wavelength`?  A scalar, list, array, something else?  Does `do something` do something to `wavelength`?

Comment: wavelength  is a number.  The most straightforward is to have them as scalars. whether storing them in other structures may help in avoid using these if else statements  what I'm asking. Those do something refers to the calculations shown in the link, which is to find three numbers (r,g,b) for a given wavelength.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are. If you have your wavelengths in a numpy array you can use [boolean masks](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) instead of the `if ... elif ...` clauses.

For your second question about the vectorized operation ... I think you want something like this:

```
wavelengths = np.array([1,2,3])
conversion = np.array([-0.41,0,0.6]).reshape(3,1) # R, G, B Parts
wavelengths * conversion
# Reshape is needed to get a 3x3 result
array([[-0.41, -0.82, -1.23],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.6 ,  1.2 ,  1.8 ]])
```

The given formulas are a bit more complicated than this example but StackOverflow isn't about writing you the code. I think with the example you should be able to implement these formulas.